# CodeIgniter ActiveRecord Multiply

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to work out the total value of all the products in my inventory. Each product in the table has a price and quantity. So I need to multiply each product's price by the quantity and then add all of these together to get a total for all products. From a previous question, I now have the MySQL query to do this:

```
select sum(product_price*product_quantity) as stockvalue from products
```

But now I'm trying to work out the correct way to do this with CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord.

Grateful for any advice on this. I've looked in the docs but can only find select_sum() for one field, rather than the sum of multiplying two together.

I have tried using the following:

```
public function getStockValue() {
$this->db->select('sum('product_price'*'product_quantity') as stockvalue', FALSE);
$this->db->from('products');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row()->stockvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('sum(`product_price`*`product_quantity`) as stockvalue', FAlSE);
```

I'm not sure if you need the second argument. I haven't worked with CI for quite awhile.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that did not work. :S

Comment: Sorry to hear that, Neil. Well, I think the only solution would be to do `$this->db->select('sum(product_price*product_quantity') as stockvalue');`. There's really no difference. You might also need to provide `false` as an additional argument argument, so CI doesn't try to protect the query.

Comment: did you try $this->db->query()

Comment: Just updated my initial question with the function I am trying. Not sure if this is the correct way to do it? :s

Comment: Nope, it is not. Use the ` sign (it should be under the escape button on your keyboard) for table names.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Thought that was maybe just the formatting from SO. Works great now. ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('sum(product_price) * sum(product_quantity) as stockvalue', FALSE);
```